# I want to run a code snippet the first time the form loads

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have a series of Windows Forms that act like a web based application. I have a form that sets a label's text to a random number and I'm trying to pass that number across other forms and be sure it updates everywhere. I don't have the ability to create a database, so  that's why I'm doing that.

The issue I have is that when I move around the application and use a button to take me back to the first page that would get the random number, the code runs again and the number changes.

```
private void goToPage2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    this.Hide();
    var form3 = new FORM3();
    form3.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

I've commented out the Close and tried Show instead of ShowDialog, but the app crashes.

Basically I just need to figure out how to go about detecting if the form has already been created once in the application's life for that time and only have the random code run that time and not every time I come back to the page via just using the app like I want it used.

I'm using Windows Forms to save time as it's just for demonstrational purposes and don't want to deal with CSS and Bootstrap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run it in the Form's [Shown event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx).

From the link:

> The Shown event is only raised the first time a form is displayed

or the [Load event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx).

From that link:

> Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.

Depending on when exactly you want it executed.

If you are creating new Forms every time and just want to know whether something happened during the course of the application execution - have a `public static bool` variable, set it when that code is executed, and check for it before that. Something like:

```
if(!Class1.theFlag)
{
    Class1.theFlag = true;
    //run your code here.
}
```

Comment: He only wants the first instance.

Comment: @SLaks I edited my answer accordingly, in case that is really what OP wants.

Comment: I just wrote out the method for the Shown event and put a messagebox in it. When I ran my program and pushed to the second form, I didn't get a message box to pop up. I manually wrote out the method and double checked with MSDN docs but it's not working. Also placed the random number snippet in the _Load method and it gets rerun when I come back to the second form.

So, if you were to be on form2 and the label read 33, you hit a button to go to form 3, then another to come back to form2 and the number reads 726 instead of what I want it to read, 33.

Comment: @TomG103 You have to subscribe to that method. Either manually: `form1.Shown += Form_Shown;` (in the constructor, for example) or in the designer (by selecting the form, and in the properties window clicking the lightning icon, and then double clicking the event needed. That will create the event handler for you.).

Comment: I did the lightning thing and the code works now, but it's still running each time I come back. Do I need to drop the "this.Close();" and change from "ShowDialog();" to "Show();"?

Comment: @TomG103 I'm not clear about which form does what in your application. If the `Form3` is the one you're talking about, then since you're creating a new one every time (`var form3 = new FORM3();`) then you'll need to create a flag variable as I mentioned later in my answer. Or change your code to just `Hide` and `ShowDialog` that same Form without recreating it every time.

Comment: How would you load a form without using the new Form();? I'm still super new to this C# stuff.

Comment: @TomG103 Create it once and assign it to a field. Then call `ShowDialog` on that field.

Comment: So just have it ShowDialog on buttonclick or something?

Comment: @TomG103 instead of `var form3 = new FORM3();
    form3.ShowDialog();` have `fieldInYourClass.ShowDialog();`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't store variables in a database and need to pass those values amongst Windows Forms, simply add a new class to the project.

Name the class whatever you want. I named my class data as well as made it a static class.

Then add methods for get and set.

```
public static int someNum
{
    get; set;
} = 0;

public static string someString
{
    get; set;
} = "";
```

So, now you can just set those values to data.someNum or data.someString instead of having to check this or that. Much quicker than so many examples I've encountered here and much less code.

I would like to thank Ispiro for his educating me here though. Thanks man.